# O que significa e como funciona um enum com o atributo [Flags]?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, atributos

Eu estava vendo como funciona a classe `FileInfo` e me deparei com um enum:

```
[Serializable]
[ComVisible(true)]
[Flags]
public enum FileAttributes
{
    ReadOnly = 1,
    Hidden = 2,
    System = 4,
    Directory = 16,
    Archive = 32,
    Device = 64,
    Normal = 128,
    Temporary = 256,
    SparseFile = 512,
    ReparsePoint = 1024,
    Compressed = 2048,
    Offline = 4096,
    NotContentIndexed = 8192,
    Encrypted = 16384,
    [ComVisible(false)]
    IntegrityStream = 32768,
    [ComVisible(false)]
    NoScrubData = 131072,
}
```

O que este atributo `[Flags]` faz?

Comment: Este link não responde nada, mas é sobre uma pergunta que fiz referente ao uso de `[Flags]`, Fica a nivel de complemento (:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12835/como-mostrar-nome-correto-em-um-enum-bitwise

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Você pode utilizar operações *bitwise* para combinar diferentes valores em apenas um.

Para acrescentar um valor utilize o [operador OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kxszd0kx.aspx):

```cs
var rgb = Cores.Vermelho | Cores.Verde | Cores.Azul;
```

Para verificar se um valor está presente utilize o [operador AND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) (ver método `HasFlag` abaixo):

```cs
if ((rgb & Cores.Azul) == Cores.Azul)
```

Para remover um valor utilize o [operador NOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d2bd4x66.aspx):

```cs
rgb &= ~Cores.Azul;
```

## Enum.HasFlag *

Se você estiver utilizando .NET 4 ou superior pode utilizar o método [HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) para verificar se o valor do enum passado está na combinação:

```
if (rgb.HasFlag(Cores.Azul))
```

## Cuidado com *não* múltiplos de dois

Como você deve ter reparado, a combinação é feita com os bits de cada valor combinado.

Ou seja, se algum dos valores não for múltiplo de dois você pode estar combinando várias *flags* de uma só vez.

Exemplo:

```
public enum Cores
{
    Vermelho = 1, // Cor primária.
    Verde = 2, // Cor primária.
    Amarelo = 3, // Cor segundária. Mistura de vermelho com verde (1 & 2).
    Azul = 4, // Cor primária.
    Magenta = 5, // Cor segundária. Mistura de vermelho e azul (1 & 4).
    Ciano = 6 // Cor segundária. Mistura de verde e azul (2 & 4).
}
```

```
var cores = Cores.Ciano | Cores.Magenta | Cores.Amarelo;
```

A variável `cores` vai possuir não só as flags `Ciano`, `Magenta` e `Amarelo` como também irá possui `Vermelho`, `Verde` e `Azul`:

```
cores.HasFlag(Cores.Vermelho); // True
cores.HasFlag(Cores.Verde); // True
cores.HasFlag(Cores.Azul); // True
```

## Mas... e o atributo *Flags* afinal?

Repare que até agora não falamos do atributo [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx). Tudo que foi dito até agora funciona sem que o enum esteja assinalado com o atributo.

A diferença entre um enum marcado com `Flags` e um não marcado é:

- Ele muda o comportamento de certos métodos como [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.enum.format.aspx) e [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/16c1xs4z.aspx).
- É especialmente útil em outras linguagens que não C#, como VB, que não suportam operações *bitwise* a *nível de linguagem*.
- Apesar de não fazer muito, acaba sendo uma boa prática pois demonstra que a intenção do enum é ser utilizado desta maneira.

*** Apesar de a documentação explicitar que o método *HasFlag* só funciona com enums marcados com *FlagsAttribute*, segundo meus testes funcionou normalmente com um enum não marcado. De qualquer forma segue o trecho:

> The HasFlag method is designed to be used with enumeration types that are marked with the FlagsAttribute attribute and can be used to determine whether multiple bit fields are set. For enumeration types that are not marked with the FlagsAttribute attribute, call either the Equals method or the CompareTo method.

Comment: Não conhecia o `HasFlag`, muito interessante.

Answer (score 5):

Um enum com este atributo permite que você coloque vários valores em uma unica variável. Por exemplo:

```
var atributosDoArquivo = FileAttributes.ReadOnly | FileAttributes.Hidden;
```

O enum marcado com o atributo `[Flags]` funciona fazendo operações *bitwise*, ou seja, em um exemplo mais simples:

```
[Flags]
public enum MeuEnum
{
    Um   = 1 << 0,       // 1
    Dois = 1 << 1,       // 2
    Tres = 1 << 2,       // 4
}
```

<sup>* Não há problema em usar o operador `<<`, pois neste caso os valores são resolvidos em tempo de compilação.</sup>

Note que para o funcionamento correto você precisa colocar o bit na posição correta, pois:

```
// valores do enum
Um   = 00000001
Dois = 00000010
Tres = 00000100
```

Então quando atribuímos dois valores deste enum para uma variável, o resultado será:

```
var resultado = MeuEnum.Um | MeuEnum.Tres; // 00000101
```

Tanto o bit de `Um` e `Tres` estão presentes no resultado, portanto esta variável contem os dois valores.

---

Caso sua variável tenha mais de um valor e você queira saber se ela contem apenas um valor, você **não deve comparar a variável diretamente** como talvez você tenha pensado em fazer, pois se ela conter mais de um valor a sua condição irá falhar.

Para saber se `resultado` tem `Um` e qualquer outro valor, compare desta forma:

```
if ((resultado & MeuEnum.Um) == MeuEnum.Um)
```

Pois

```
// resultado & MeuEnum.Um == MeuEnum.Um
(00000101 & 00000001) = 00000001
```

Caso queira remover apenas um valor mantendo todos outros, você pode usar:

```
resultado &= ~MeuEnum.Um;
```

Pois

```
// resultado & inverso de Um = Tres
00000101     & 11111110      = 00000100
```

Mais aqui sobre [operadores em C# na MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

Comment: +1 pelo uso do operador `<<`