# Como eliminar um arquivo marcado com o atributo "Somente leitura"?

Tags: c#, .net

Estou tentando excluir um arquivo que está marcado com o atributo "Somente leitura":

[image: somente leitura]

Sempre que o arquivo está marcado com o referido atributo, recebo a seguinte exceção:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled

Se for um arquivo cujo atributo "Somente leitura" está desmarcado, o processo de exclusão é realizado sem problemas.

### Como faço para remover arquivos marcados com este atributo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## System.IO.File

```
File.SetAttributes(caminhoDoArquivo, ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
File.Delete(caminhoDoArquivo);
```

## System.IO.FileInfo (via propriedade)

```
fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
fileInfo.Delete();
```

## System.IO.FileInfo (via atributo)

```
fileInfo.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
fileInfo.Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Para remover o somente leitura você precisa remover este atributo. Para isto você pode utilizar a classe `FileInfo`.

```
var info = new FileInfo("teste.txt");
```

E acessar a propriedade `Attributes` que é [enum com flags (leia mais)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1594/40). Com isto você pode remover o atributo `ReadOnly` e seu arquivo poderá ser apagado.

```
new FileInfo("test.txt").Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione esse assembly:

```
using System.IO;
```

Adicione essa linha DEPOIS de declarado o diretório:

```
File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
//path = Diretório
```

`.Hidden` = Propriedade.

Exemplo:

- *.Normal*, para normal.
- *.ReadOnly*, para somente leitura.
- *.Archive* para backup, etc...

Mais info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes(v=vs.110).aspx