# Como mostrar nome correto em um enum bitwise?

Tags: c#, enums, bitwise

Eu tenho o seguinte enum marcado como `[Flag]`, ou seja, são valores em bit

```
[Flags]
public enum Position
{
    None,
    Left,
    Right,
    Both=3
}
```

Setei para `Both`(ambos) posição em `3` por que se for `Left` e `Right` ao mesmo tempo, deve ser igual a `Both` (1+2=3)
Mas quando eu chamo o Both no ToString e aparece como `"Left | Right"`. Como faço para ele aparecer como `"Both"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remova o atributo `Flags`... pois é exatamente para isso que serve o atributo Flags, para indicar que existe uma combinação de valores... se você quer mostrar um valor sem considerá-lo como sendo uma combinação, então porque usar `Flags`?

Note que um enum não necessita do atributo `Flags` para ser usado como tal. Além disso, eu especificaria os valores todos manualmente para evitar futuros erros:

```
public enum Position
{
    None - 0,
    Left = 1,
    Right = 2,
    Both = 3
}
```

Ainda assim você pdoerá fazer isso:

```
Position pos = Position.Left | Position.Right;
```

E na hora de fazer o teste bitwise, pode usar o **operador bitwise &**, de forma a isolar o bit desejado, assim:

```
if ((pos & Position.Left) != 0)
{
    // código para quando o bit Position.Left está definido
}
```

Ou então o contrário:

```
if ((pos & Position.Left) == 0)
{
    // código para quando o bit Position.Left está zerado
}
```

Comment: Sim, eu expecifico `Both` como 3 porque o default dele seria 4 com `[Flags]`. É que em certos trechos de código eu sempre preciso comparar o seguinte: 
`GameResult.PlayerPirate = playAs == Position.Right || playAs == Position.Both ? PlayerType.Human : PlayerType.Computer;`
Então se for `Left` ou `Both` faça tal coisa. Mas muito obrigado, era bem isso mesmo o erro.

Comment: Adicionei detalhe sobre como fazer a verificação de forma mais simples.

Comment: Sim, a forma como eu fiz no outro comentario é antes de saber que existia o bitwise (: então fui usar e surgiu a dúvida.
Isso vai simplificar muito as verificações aqui, muito obrigado!